# batch file to calculate eacho six numbers alone without external file (cmd only)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, numbers

i want batch file to calculate each six numbers alone for example

this is the full part

896596458923387467826475579837

and the batch file will calculate first six (896596) and division the numbers with 2 (896596/2) and continue with all numbers

(i want the code work with numbers bigger than this means if i but numbers bigger than this it will calculate with this Technic)

Comment: Your pattern is not clear. Provide a better explanation.

Comment: Batch can't handle math with numbers bigger than 32767. Best case scenario, you'd have to use a hybrid script.

Comment: @SomethingDark: The arithmetic operations of `set /A` command uses 32-bits wide integer numbers with a maximum value of 2147483647 (`set /A 0x7FFFFFFF`).

Comment: So it does. I wonder why I thought it was 16-bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program:

```
@echo off

set string=896596458923387467826475579837
echo String: %string%

:getNextGroup
   set group=%string:~0,6%
   set /A division=group/2
   echo %group% divided by 2 gives %division%
   set string=%string:~6%
if defined string goto getNextGroup
```

Produce this output:

```
String: 896596458923387467826475579837
896596 divided by 2 gives 448298
458923 divided by 2 gives 229461
387467 divided by 2 gives 193733
826475 divided by 2 gives 413237
579837 divided by 2 gives 289918
```

Is this what you want?